# Mathematical Calculations in a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, mathematical-expressions

In my project I have following database tables:

```
Course
-------
1.Course Id 
2.Course Name
3.Term Name

Subject
-------
1.Subject Id
2.Subject Name
3.Term Name

Term
-----
1.Term Id
2.Term Name
3.Total Working Days

Working Day
-------------
1.Work day Id
2.Term Id

Staff_work
-----------
1.Staff Id
2.Work day Id
3.Staff Working hour per day

Period
-------
1.Period Id
2.period Name
```

If I choose Term Id and Course Id 
Table will be generated with

```
Periods Day 1   Day 2           Day 3           Day 4           Day 5   
period 1    Subject name    Subject name    Subject name    Subject name        
Period 2    Subject name    Subject name    Subject name    Subject name
```

It matches Staff Working hour per day,Total Working Days
is this calculations possible in SQL?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.  Please try it and post what you have tried.

Comment: provide some sample data in sqlfidle